# Vivaldi Browser storing Cookies in Chrome Safe Store

Tags: browser, cookies, keychain, vivaldi

On my OSX machine Vivaldi always starts with the [message](https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/9115/vivaldi-trying-to-use-confidential-data-form-chrome-safe-storage)

> Vivaldi wants to use your confidential information saved in "Chrome Safe Store" in your keychain.

If I deny this request, all cookies from the previous sessions will not be loaded, starting with 0 cookies. This means I cannot use the "remember me" or "auto log me in next time" feature of any page.

If I allow the request, 200 cookies will be loaded including the ones from "remember me" login forms.

Is there a way for Vivaldi to save Cookies without mixing them up with Chrome? I want the two browsers to be isolated from each other.